# Ruby: more efficient way to convert table_name into object Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So.. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
"active_record_object" => ActiveRecordObject
```

with the following code:

```
ar_object = (object.singularize.split("_").each{|o| o.capitalize!}).join.constantize #convert to ActiveRecord object
```

is there a more efficient way to do this? chaining 7 string manipulation methods together seems a lil crazy for ruby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a method called `classify` for that:

```
"active_record_object".classify
 # => "ActiveRecordObject"
```

Edit: as pointed out in the comments, `"active_record_object".classify.constantize` gets you all the way.

Comment: `"active_record_object".classify.constantize` is actually what OP wants